# ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-14

I changed my PC, and checkout the project to the new PC, when I build with my war, it gives this error but with my another PC it builds correctly, I use grails SDK 2.3.11. I don't don't know what the error can be..

when I build with my old pc it works correctly, I double checked all configuration and seems all correct.

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: privateserver/BulkExportService$EmptyResults, method: super$1$stream signature: ()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: privateserver/BulkExportService$EmptyResults, method: super$1$stream signature: ()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: privateserver/BulkExportService$EmptyResults, method: super$1$stream signature: ()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
        at privateserver.BulkExportService.<clinit>(BulkExportService.groovy:198)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        ... 5 more








<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
        <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="grailsResourceLoader" ref="grailsResourceLoader" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
        <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="grailsApplication" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsResourceLoader" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="characterEncodingFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
        <property name="encoding">
            <value>utf-8</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Which JDK are you using?  It will need to be Java 7 or prior.

Comment: I was using 1.7 now 1.8, in my other PC that works I use 1.8 also.

Comment: "I was using 1.7 now 1.8, in my other PC that works I use 1.8 also" - Grails 2.5 is the first version for which we support Java 8.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown You mean that with 1.8 is impossible to build with grails 2.3.11?

Comment: "You mean that with 1.8 is impossible to build with grails 2.3.11?" - Sort of.  I am not saying that it is impossible.  I am saying that we don't support it, and there are a lot of things that won't work.

Comment: Thank you @JeffScottBrown, there is no different between open JDK and oracle to use, right?

Comment: "there is no different between open JDK and oracle to use, right?" -  Both are supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on your "BulkExportService" which probably not support with java 1.8 .

Comment: Yes, you are right, after uncomment the class it deploy correctly. thank you

Answer (score 1):

JDK 8 is not supported for Grails 2.3.11.  Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we added support for Java 8.